# How can I access the element in a __init__() method in a tkinter class?

Tags: python

I'm trying to access an element from a list that is created in the following. The program switches between multiple pages, and I want receive input from the user to store as a string in another file.

```
class SignupPage(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):

        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, bg='light blue')

        ulabel = tk.Label(self, text="User Name").pack()
        uname = tk.StringVar()
        uEntry = tk.Entry(self, textvariable=uname). pack()

        plabel = tk.Label(self, text='Password').pack()
        psswd = tk.StringVar()
        pEntry = tk.Entry(self, textvariable=psswd).pack()

        def Signup():
            username = uname.get()
            password = psswd.get()

            credentials_list = [username, password]
            print(credentials_list)
            print(username, password)

            controller.show_frame(SignupPage2)

        nextbutton = tk.Button(self, text='Next', command=Signup).pack()
        backbutton = tk.Button(
            self, text='Back', command=lambda: controller.show_frame(WelcomePage)).pack()
```

I want to access the username variable in another file, so I imported the class SignupPage.

```
from app import SignupPage
```

However, trying to access the element by typing the following doesn't work.

```
print(SignupPage.__init__.Signup.credentials_list[0])
```

How can I access the username variable?

Comment: Unrelated to your question: Don't assign the result of calling `pack()` to a variable — i.e. `ulabel = tk.Label(self, text="User Name").pack()` — because it's always `None`. Create the widget and assign it to a variable, then call variable.pack()` in a separate statement.

Comment: `credentials_list` is what's known as a "Local Variable". It cannot be accessed by simply stringing together the random assortment of names. Try changing `credentials_list` to `self.credentials_list`, to change it into an attribute of the object, and then you will be able to access `object.credentials_list` outside of the class. Also is the indentation in the question how it is supposed to look?

Comment: @AJ123 the indentation should be fixed now after fixing the formatting

Comment: I would also recommend making the `Signup()` function a separate method. This way you could return credentials_list from it when you call the method.

Answer (score 0):

Let's start with the following function inside your `SignupPage` class`:

```
def Signup():
    username = uname.get()
    password = psswd.get()

    ...
```

You want to access `username` inside that function. Unfortunately, `username` only exists inside `Signup()`, and cannot be accessed by using the dot operator. The same goes for the rest of the variables inside the function. So, you cannot get the username value by using

```
SignupPage.__init__.Signup.credentials_list[0]
```

We have to do something else. One thing we could do is put `Signup()` outside of `__init__()` and give `SignupPage` some instance variables. The `SignupPage` class would look something like the following.

```
class SignupPage(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, bg='light blue')

        self.credentials_list = list()

        ulabel = tk.Label(self, text="User Name").pack()
        self.uname = tk.StringVar()
        uEntry = tk.Entry(self, textvariable=self.uname). pack()

        plabel = tk.Label(self, text='Password').pack()
        self.psswd = tk.StringVar()
        pEntry = tk.Entry(self, textvariable=self.psswd).pack()

        nextbutton = tk.Button(self, text='Next', command=self.Signup).pack()
        backbutton = tk.Button(self, text='Back', command=lambda: controller.show_frame(WelcomePage)).pack()
        self.pack()

    def Signup(self):
        username = self.uname.get()
        password = self.psswd.get()

        self.credentials_list = [username, password]
        print(self.credentials_list)
        print(username, password)

        controller.show_frame(SignupPage2)
```

With this one, when we press the "Next" button, an instance of the `SignupPage` class will hold the values entered in the username and password text fields. To create an instance of the class, we simply do:

```
# root = tk.Tk()
signupPage = SignupPage(root, controller)
```

At this point, we can now access `credentials_list` by doing:

```
signupPage.credentials_list
```

Remember to pass the same instance of `SignupPage` to anything that will get the value of any attributes the class has.

I reckon that what I suggested is not the best design, but it should at least give you an idea on how to solve your problem.

---

**Side Note**: One way you can improve upon this is to use to provide a getter method for `SignupPage` that returns the value of `credentials_list`, instead of having to access the aforementioned variable by doing `<instance>.credentials_list`. Doing this is generally a better programming practice than the other method.

Comment: I used this but I get the following: 
```File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/tkinter/__init__.py", line 2143, in pack_configure
    + self._options(cnf, kw))
_tkinter.TclError: cannot use geometry manager pack inside .!frame which already has slaves managed by grid```

Comment: What's the full traceback? You can put it in a pastebin.